# Obtener los registros que no están en otra tabla Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hoy vengo a preguntarles sobre una consulta en oracle, quiero saber si existe un registro en otra tabla  con un filtro de periodo de tiempo en este caso fecha de registro.

Lo que trato de hacer es que si existen datos en la tabla de guardado estos no se reflejen en una consulta donde filtro por fecha y no de vuelo.

En mi consulta cuando pongo exist me marca ese registro que esta en la tabla pero cuando pongo not exist me aparecen muchos registros repetidos y no me aparece el filtro de fecha, ni los demas.

Para enlazarlos ocupo los parametros que estan ahi, para tabla master : numidentificador, consgentrada y master , tabla house registro, house, identificador, consigentrada y la tercera tiene ambos datos de la 1 y 2.

De antemano gracias, espero me puedan orientar.

```
SELECT --distinct 
       m.fst01_guiamaster, h.fst02_guiahouse,  h.fst02_noregistro , h.fst01_consigentrada,
         m.fst01_novuelo, h.fst02_fechaentpais, h.fst02_almacencapt, h.fsc10_cveoperacion
         FROM  --fst04_guardado c , 
         fst01_capturamaster m, fst02_capturahouse h 
    WHERE not  EXISTS (
    
    SELECT *-- distinct --c.fst01_guiamaster, c.fst02_guiahouse, 
          --c.fst02_noregistro
         --m.fst01_novuelo, h.fst02_fechaentpais, h.fst02_almacencapt, h.fsc10_cveoperacion
         FROM  fst04_guardado c 
         WHERE      c.fst01_numidentificador = h.fst01_numidentificador
                AND c.fst02_noregistro = h.fst02_noregistro
                AND c.fst02_guiahouse = h.fst02_guiahouse
                AND c.fst01_consigentrada = h.fst01_consigentrada
                AND (h.fst02_almacencapt  = '22'
                AND h.fsc10_cveoperacion = '02')
                AND to_char(h.fst02_fechaentpais, 'DD/MM/YYYY') ='14/04/2023'
    AND m.fst01_novuelo = '626'
               
    
    )
```

Comment: Leí la pregunta dos veces y no logro dar con lo que quieres. Sugiero dos alternativas: Que expliques qué datos hay en cada tabla y lo que quieres lograr, en un lenguaje coloquial, como se lo dirías a tu tía, y no en términos de tablas ni de queryes. La otra es que reduzcas el problema a un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), qutándo todo aquello que no interesa ni hace falta para entenderlo.

Comment: Ya lo logre solucionar, igual les comparto mi solucion.

Comment: Enhorabuena y adelante, escribe la respuesta a tu pregunta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Los solucione con left join para que cuando la relacion Registro exista no se muestre el registro de la tabla guardado.  Esto lo habia visto en otras publicaciones pero no lo habia intentado porque usualmente en donde lo ocupo no los ocupan y el not exist no me conectaba del todo.

Y como  contiene varias relaciones de llaves foraneas las enlace para evitar registros repetidos de las dos tablas enlazadas.

Espero a alguien  le pueda funcionar o ocupar en algun momento mas adelante, agradezco que se tomaran el tiempo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                                    h.fst02_almacencapt,
                                    h.fsc10_cveoperacion,
                                    m.fst01_numidentificador
                                FROM
                                    fst02_capturahouse        h
                                    LEFT JOIN fst01_capturamaster      m  ON (h.fst01_guiamaster = m.fst01_guiamaster)
                                                                          AND ( h.fst01_numidentificador = m.fst01_numidentificador )
                                                                          AND ( h.fst01_consigentrada = m.fst01_consigentrada )
                                    LEFT JOIN fst04_guardado  c  ON ( h.fst01_consigentrada = c.fst01_consigentrada )
                                                                          AND ( h.fst01_numidentificador = c.fst01_numidentificador )
                                                                          AND ( h.fst02_noregistro = c.fst02_noregistro )
                                                                          AND ( h.fst01_guiamaster = c.fst01_guiamaster)
                                WHERE
                                    h.fst02_almacencapt = pstralmacen
                                    AND h.fsc10_cveoperacion = '02'
                                    AND m.fst01_novuelo = pstrnovuelo
                                    AND to_char(h.fst02_fechaentpais, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = pstrfechavuelo
                                    AND c.fst02_noregistro IS NULL;
```